# Make a scroll bar in my search javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

i have a problem in my search bar in my javascript because i have a 2k+ names stored in my table called tb_applicants....if i type f or something it will give me a very long list of names started with the letter i type...i want to do is put a scroll bar on it so that it wont be long just like a combobox.

[image]

current code:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="search" id="query"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#query").autocomplete({
        source : 'search.php',
        select : function(event,ui){
            $("#query").html(ui.item.value);
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

search.php code:

```
<?php

$q = $_GET['term'];

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("klayton");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT name 
FROM tb_applicants
WHERE name LIKE '$q%' LIMIT 5");

$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$data[]=array('value'=>$row['name']);
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the jqueryUI plugin you just have to set the max-height CSS property as explained at:

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#maxheight

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you can do it in CSS only by defining the height or max-height to your #query element, and probably setting overflow-y to auto.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/UYpP6/

```css
#query {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Just add that code I wrote into your css file and modify the max-height value to suit your own needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu {
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```